# Link error when compile mex files

Tags: macos, matlab, linker, mex

I am running mex under MATLAB R2011a in OS X 10.8.
The compiling process is almost OK.
But I come into some link errors.
The command line I used in MATLAB command window is:

```
mex -I/usr/include/ -L/usr/lib/ -O -DDEBUG -DFASTPLOG CalcEntropyScalesOpt.c  Hists.c
```

The original command line which runs well in MS Windows is

```
mex -O -DDEBUG -DFASTPLOG CalcEntropyScalesOpt.c  Hists.c
```

I add those -I and -L options to fix some errors. But link errors still exist:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_mxCreateDoubleMatrix_700", referenced from:
  _do_CalcSalScale1DAA in CalcEntropyScalesOpt.o
  _do_CalcSalScale3D in CalcEntropyScalesOpt.o
  _do_CalcSalScale2D in CalcEntropyScalesOpt.o
  _do_CalcSalScale1DParzen in CalcEntropyScalesOpt.o
  _do_CalcSalScale1D in CalcEntropyScalesOpt.o
"_mxCreateNumericArray_700", referenced from:
  _AACirclePix in CalcEntropyScalesOpt.o
  _CirclePix2 in CalcEntropyScalesOpt.o
... many more like this ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

mex: link of ' "CalcEntropyScalesOpt.mexmaci64"' failed.
```

I think I need some more -l or -L options, but don't know what to write there.

Thanks.

Regards,
Richard

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.

The library needed is mx (libmx.dylib).
It is under MATLABROOT/bin/maci64 and is OK.
But there is a false symbolic link in /usr/lib.
The linker actually linked that file, which points to some libSystem.dylib.
I removed that link and everything goes well.